# Python code refactoring question. Simplification

Tags: python, refactoring, list

I have code that looks something like this:

```
self.ui.foo = False
self.ui.bar = False
self.ui.item = False
self.ui.item2 = False 
self.ui.item3 = False
```

And I would like to turn it into something like this:

```
items = [foo,bar,item,item2,item3]
for elm in items:
    self.ui.elm = False
```

But obviously just having the variables in the list with out the 'self.ui' part is invalid, and I would rather not type out 'self.ui' for every element in the list, because that really isn't to much better.  How could I rewrite my first code to make it something like what I'm talking about?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's how you do that:

```
items = ['foo','bar','item','item2','item3']
for elm in items:
    setattr(self.ui, elm, False)
```

Answer (score 4):

`items` needs to be a list of strings.

```
items = ['foo', 'bar', 'item', 'item2', 'item3']
for elm in items:
    setattr(self.ui, elm, False)
```